# Do dependencies get downloaded before or after the npm preinstall script?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

The docs for NPM Scripts state:

> preinstall: Run BEFORE the package is installed

But does this occur before or after dependencies are downloaded?

That is, which of these is correct:

1. Download Dependencies
2. Pre-install script run
3. Installation

or

1. Pre-install script run
2. Install

   1. Download Dependencies as part of the installation

I couldn't see this covered by the [npm script docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), but it's possible it's documented elsewhere.

Comment: Have you seen behaviour that suggests it's running part-way through the install process not prior to it? The pre- hooks in general run strictly *before* the script that's prefixed, and the download is part of the install script.

Comment: @jonrsharpe knowning that the dep download is part of the install is the answer to my question. In particular a colleague wants to download a dependency without it runnign scripts, so they're putting that `npm i dep@1.0.1 --ignore-scripts` in the pre-install, and trying to exclude it from the main dependency download. That woudn't work if scenario 1 was the case.

Comment: Could someone help explain what is not clear about my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also searched for the answer to this question and haven't found any documentation outlining the exact process.

However, from testing, it seems to depend. If you run `npm link` or `npm install` within a package directory, it will download dependencies and run scripts, but in this order:

1. Run preinstall script
2. Download dependencies
3. Run postinstall script

Therefore, if your preinstall script uses dependencies, it will fail.

But if you run `npm install <package>` or `npm install <path/to/local/folder>` from another folder, it will do it in this order:

1. Download or link package + all dependencies
2. Run preinstall script
3. Run postinstall script

Comment: Not sure if things have changed since 2019, but I am seeing the same order in both of these cases, where it: 
1. Download or link package + all dependencies
2. Run preinstall script
3. Run postinstall script